# How to link a website using barcode scanner

Tags: android, qr-code, barcode-scanner

I have made an app that scans Barcodes/QR. I want to be able to scan the recipt and have it take me to that direct site.

EX. I Scan a barcode and i want it to go directly to a survey and pass up all the other website options.
Such as a survey for a store, instead of typing in the whole site I would just to go there directly with a scan.

Comment: such things are integrated in the barcode itself.....

Comment: Go throw this tutorial i think it will be help to you ... https://www.spaceotechnologies.com/qr-code-android-using-zxing-library/.
You only need to change one thing when you get the link you have to just redirect it to that link.. Hope this will be useful for you .

Comment: Most barcodes are scanned and work like a keyboard. You can do a lot of characters and control codes as such. You really can make an absurd malicious barcode that will hack a system. Though you don't have many characters to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QRCode has this feature built-in.

You just need to make sure the URL you encoded is a complete website URL, i.e., with the prefix http:// or https://.

If you encode the content as www.example.org, then the URL will not be opened.

Comment: where at would i put this link for it to work exactly? and there must be more code to back up what i want to do.